# How to set custom date array in date picker dialog?

Tags: android, datepicker

I want set custom date array in the date picker dialog. date array is not in sequence date. So how can i set custom array in date picker.
Please Help.

Comment: add code what you tried so far ?

Comment: I think you need to provide more information on why not `updateDate` is good enough..
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#updateDate%28int,%20int,%20int%29

Answer (score 2):

Here is example

Forget about DatePickerDialog, Just
   Build Custom dialog with NumberPicker Widget and add code like

```
NumberPicker picker = new NumberPicker(this);
picker.setMinValue(0);
picker.setMaxValue(2);
picker.setDisplayedValues( new String[] { "Belgium", "France", "United Kingdom" } );
```

Just replace new String[] { "Belgium", "France", "United Kingdom" } with your ArrayList.

here is [link](http://androidnutts.blogspot.in/2013/09/number-picker-dialog.html) for simple number picker.

Comment: thanks, But how can i set all the arrayList string date in the Datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

Use NumberPicker and set your custom date array as string.

```
NumberPicker mDateNumberPicker= new NumberPicker(this);
mDateNumberPicker.setMinValue(0);
mDateNumberPicker.setMaxValue(5);
mDateNumberPicker.setDisplayedValues( new String[] { "25-5-2010" ,"25-5-2011", "25-5-2012", "25-5-2013","25-5-2014","25-5-2015" } );
```